Trying to remap Cmd+W to Cmd+H using Karabiner-Elements
I'm using Karabiner-Elements to remap Cmd+W to Cmd+H. (This helps prevent me from closing a window so that when I switch to the app using Cmd+Tab, the window will appear, which only happens for open windows.)
From what I can tell, this appears to be possible, and I've created the following JSON to create a complex modification, but I'm not getting it to work. Any ideas are much appreciated.
{
    "description": "Swap \"command + w\" with \"command + h\" ",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "from": {
                "key_code": "w",
                "modifiers": {
                    "mandatory": ["command"],
                    "optional": ["any"]
                }
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "h",
                    "modifiers": ["command"]
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}


I don't really understand what the purpose of this is. Cmd/W is a global command, though you could override it in system settings for a given app. Replacing it with another global command for Hide doesn't really seem like a good idea.

@Tetsujin The purpose of this is in the post. Neither Cmd + W or Cmd + H is typically a destructive command so why not a good idea?

I found out why this was happening. My external Magic Keyboard wasn't enabled in the Devices panel.

